# unable to connect talend DI to mySQL

Tags: mysql, talend

HI im trying to connect talend di to mysql localhost database but im getting failled connection error,

I dont understand why, I switched off firewall

```
Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
   48 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Check the connections Credentials also in Talend Preferences Setting -> Under Connections check the settings for proxy bypass and other proxy settings.

Comment: Check for the setting are correct and is your machine localhost entry being enterd in native/mannual settings in Talend Prefrences Connections tab.

Comment: just check that localhost is blocked from network settings in talend in general tab

Comment: that still doesn't mean anything? what values should be in there? what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you elaborate what error you are getting or can you upload the screen shot , because if you are not able to connect to database on your local machine then , Your proxy is blocking from Talend or the user with which you are trying to connect doesn't exist.To

Answer (score 0):

check your proxy connections i.e., under `control panel -> Internet Options-> connections -> LAN Settings`
1) Deactivate "Automatically detect settings" and deactivate "Use automatic configuration script"
2) Activate "Use a proxy server for your LAN", enter xxxx Your Proxy Here xxxxxx and port 8080
3) Activate "Bypass proxy for local addresses"

Under Advanced tab give your proxy address for HTTP, Secure, FTP. If you are working under a company give your exceptions under exceptions box there.

Now Open Talend Studio
under `window -> preferences -> General -> Double click on Network connections` and there you see all the proxys you have given and mark the `Active Provider` drop down as `Native` click apply and ok